# C# ASP.NET DataGrid Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, checkbox, bind

I have an Editable Data grid which is pulling data from a SQL query one of the field has a Y or N answer and therefore needs to be a checkbox however in Edit Mode it shows as a field and errors if I put this in

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ALFSUPR" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("pric_c_alfsupreq") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
```

Is there a simple way of converting the Text Field to a CheckBox which when Checked has a value = Y

Thanks

Comment: What kind of control you're using in the .aspx page? DataGrid or DataGridView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Checked='<%# Eval("pric_c_alfsupreq").ToString().Equals("Y") %>'>
```

**UPDATE:**

Since you're using an old **DataGrid** (you should be using **DataGridView** nowadays), you should have something similar to this in your `DataGrid` definition:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="Grid" runat="server" PageSize="5" AllowPaging="True"
              DataKeyField="EmpId" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
              ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="No" 
              OnPageIndexChanged="Grid_PageIndexChanged"
              OnCancelCommand="Grid_CancelCommand" 
              OnDeleteCommand="Grid_DeleteCommand"
              OnEditCommand="Grid_EditCommand"
              OnUpdateCommand="Grid_UpdateCommand">
```

See the **OnUpdateCommand**...

Now the method that should run when you're applying an update to the row's data:

```
protected void Grid_UpdateCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connect"]);

    char value = "N"

    // You'll have to change the index here to point to the CheckBox you have in
    // your DataGrid.
    // It can be on index 1 Controls[1] or 2 Controls[2]. Only you know this info.
    if(((CheckBox)e.Item.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Checked == true)
    {
         value = "Y";;
    }

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pric_c_alfsupreq", SqlDbType.Char).Value = value;

    cmd.CommandText = "Update command HERE";

    cmd.Connection = con;

    cmd.Connection.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.Connection.Close();

    Grid.EditItemIndex = -1;
}
```

Hope you get the idea. If you need this code in any other moment you can place it in the `OnEditCommand`, `OnDeleteCommand`, etc...

Comment: This works it puts a checkbox into the form and thats great, however when I update it doesn't set the value but it doesn't error either any ideas?

Comment: I am struggling to understand this can you explain further I need to write a Y or N into the field on the database when I when i check the box or not

Comment: You have to convert the value back to your database. When the user check or uncheck the box it has true or false. You'll have to convert this value to Y or N so that it's like what you have in the DB. The DataGrid must have a OnUpdating event that should allow you to make the value conversion before sending it to the DB.

Comment: Hi thanks for the above it turns out I am using <asp:GridView> is the process the same as above?

Comment: Yes, but with the GridView you'd use the OnRowUpdating command: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html

Answer (score 2):

Can't really remember my WebForms days, but possibly change the

```
Checked='<%# Bind("pric_c_alfsupreq") %>'>
```

to

```
Checked='<%# Eval("pric_c_alfsupreq") == "Y" %>'>
```

When you update, I think you'll have to handle the GridView.RowUpdating event, then extract the Checked property, convert it to "Yes" or "No".

Answer (score 2):

If your code requires a bit more logic than Simon's answer, you can also create a protected method in your code behind and call it.

```
protected bool GetCheckboxValue(String value)
{
    //put your logic here
    return value.ToLower() == "y";
}
```

and then call it with

```
Checked='<%# GetCheckboxValue("pric_c_alfsupreq") %>'>
```